# Codeigniter Url Rewriting without any controller or method or any other word except domain name/ product name

Tags: codeigniter-routing

I need to change my Url's from http://www.website.com/controller-name/method-name/id/
to http://www.website.com/Art-Coupon-Codes this is a single example.How can this be done in codeigniter

Comment: can you clear your question?

Comment: Basically i don't want any controller, method or any other word except domainname/product-name